# Custom CSS menu, "Active" tab remains on 'Home' not the actual page

Tags: css, menu

I created this custom css menu, but when switching tabs, the "Active" tab design remains on the 'Home' link on the menu, rather than the actual page I'm on. Any idea how I an fix this?

**HTML :**

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="http://caribbeantl.com/"; class="active"><span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://caribbeantl.com/hotels/"><span>Testing post</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS :**

```
.menu {margin:0 auto; padding:0; height:30px; width:100%; display:block; background:url('http://media.datahc.com/Affiliates/43817/Brands/Image/topmenuimages.png') repeat-x;}
.menu li {padding:0; margin:0; list-style:none; display:inline;}
.menu li a {float:left; padding-left:15px; display:block; color:rgb(255,255,255); text-decoration:none; font:12px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; cursor:pointer; background:url('http://media.datahc.com/Affiliates/43817/Brands/Image/topmenuimages.png') 0px -30px no-repeat;}
.menu li a span {line-height:30px; float:left; display:block; padding-right:15px; background:url('http://media.datahc.com/Affiliates/43817/Brands/Image/topmenuimages.png') 100% -30px no-repeat;}
.menu li a:hover {background-position:0px -60px; color:rgb(255,255,255);}
.menu li a:hover span {background-position:100% -60px;}
.menu li a.active,
.menu li a.active:hover {line-height:30px; font:12px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; background:url('http://media.datahc.com/Affiliates/43817/Brands/Image/topmenuimages.png') 0px -90px no-repeat; color:rgb(255,255,255);}
.menu li a.active span,
.menu li a.active:hover span {background:url('http://media.datahc.com/Affiliates/43817/Brands/Image/topmenuimages.png') 100% -90px no-repeat;}
```

Comment: Remove the semicolon in the first A tag.

Answer (score 3):

HTML:

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
  <li><a class="menuLink active" href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li> <a class="menuLink" href="#">Page1</a></li>
  <li><a class="menuLink" href="#">Page2</a></li>
  <li><a class="menuLink" href="#">Page3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

css:

```
.menu
{
height:64px;
width:100%;
background-repeat:repeat-x;
text-align:center;
 }

.menuLink, .menuLink:visited
{
 color:#00000;
background-image:url(img/btk.png);
text-decoration:none;
font-size: 20px;
width:70px;
height: 50px;
padding: 10px;
display:block;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-right: 10px;
margin-top: 6px;
}
.menuLink:hover
{
color:#CC7011;
background-color:aqua;
font-size: 26px;
}
.active{
background-color:aqua;
}
ul,li{
display:inline-block;
list-style:none;
line-height:60px;
vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

​
jquery:

```
$('.menuLink').click(function(){
  $('a').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});​
```

Live Demo
http://jsfiddle.net/PYW35/

Comment: OP did not tag it with jquery, better to try plain JavaScript first

Answer (score 1):

First you have an extraneous semicolon in in the first `<li>`

You need to move the `class="active"` to the `<li>` that you want to be active.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact answer to it but, I would say to find something that gets the url and if it matches the link in the bar then that would get class active, else, none are active.

Answer (score 0):

I thing you need some JavaScript to get it done,

[Here is the simple demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/H9HHq/)

Hope this helps

**Note : `getElementsByClassName()` not supported by some browsers**

Take a look on the following [comparison table](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#fivemethods)

Comment: Ah thanks! I'm not sure where I add the JavaScript code though?

Comment: @user1690254 it is better to embed your script tag at the bottom of the body tag. for eg. `...<script>//js code goes here...</script></body>`

Comment: Hi, thanks. I did that but still no luck I'm afraid. You can see it here if you have some time http://tripoasis.com/

Comment: @user1690254 The site you mentioned is under maintenance!

Comment: Ah apologies, should be open now.

Comment: @user1690254 Ok, JavaScript wont help in this case, since the page getting reloaded. Are you using common layout for header for all pages? if so, one way you can go for is maintain a tab selection in session, then check the selection in the layout and change the class according to that.

Comment: This may be a tad bit too complicated for my ability in coding, I'll have to look at other menu options or use a a default Wordpress one. Thanks though ;)